# CreateProcess weird behavior with files without extension

Tags: winapi

I have noticed this behavior:

There are 2 executable files in the current dir, named 'somefile' and 'somefile.abc'.

`CreateProcessA(NULL, "somefile", ...)` - fails with error code 2 (`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`)

`CreateProcessA(NULL, "somefile.abc", ...)` - works

`CreateProcessA(NULL, ".\\somefile", ...)` - works

`CreateProcessA(NULL, ".\\somefile.abc", ...)` - works

So, it looks like the ".\" is mandatory if and only if the file doesn't have an extension.
Is there a logic behind this behavior?

Comment: A file with no extension should still end with a `.` though?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The second arg to CreateProcess should not be const string. If you are passing some const string, then pass that in first arg and make the 2nd arg NULL.

Comment: Every file should have a `.`, then the extension, if there's no extension, it will just look like `myfile.`, either way it ends in `.`, not just `myfile`

Comment: @Abhineet: the second arg can be a const string in `CreateProcessA()`, which the OP's example is using.  It is only `CreateProcessW()` that requires a non-const string. This is clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Oops...

Comment: It was my mistake, it won't compile, obviously, but everyone got the idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the file name does not contain an extension, .exe is appended. Therefore, if the file name extension is .com, this parameter must include the .com extension. If the file name ends in a period (.) with no extension, or if the file name contains a path, .exe is not appended.

I don't know if the documented behavior should be called "weird".

Comment: Yes, this behavior should be called "weird" even though it is documeneted... A lot of people will stumbe over that a parameter named lpCommandLine doesn#t take a command-line but something close to that....

Comment: @moritz A lot of people do not read publicly accessible documentation on the technology they are trying to work with. It's a pity.

Comment: Normally the first parameter should be used to run an executable. In that case, even an executable without an extension can actually run.